# Drupal modules for editing data in Views

Tags: drupal, view

I need to give to users abvility to edit the nodes from the views results.
I have found several good modules like jEditable and editablefield but the doesnt fiit my need perfectly
So what I need.
1. Drupal 7 compatibility.
2. For example I have a view that have generated several rows. I need that every row has ONE "Edit button" that make ALL fields of this editable.

Please help me to find such module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure a module exists that does exactly what you want.  The closest that I know is [Slickgrid](http://drupal.org/project/slickgrid).